# Is this LCA algorithm ok, used elsewhere?

Tags: graph-algorithm, least-common-ancestor

we needed to get LCA when merging two
histories of data changes, with a very large no of histories and nodes in each history; with branching and merging happening - so to find LCA for 2 histories starting from 2 points we must search backwards across any no of histories, not just walk back along the two given histories.

The published ways for finding LCA seem to assume a pre-scan of all the nodes as the 1st phase, and we wanted to avoid that.

Looked at using a vector clock with each node in history - then we wouldn't need to do any search at all, just knowing the VC's of two starting nodes would give us the VC of the LCA. But had problems with VCs, as we have a large and dynamic no of histories and nodes.

Instead of VC we used a simple scalar counter (similar to the logical clock, used elsewhere) and we do need to do partial search but complexity is expected to be lower. The code seems to work ok. I wonder if anyone else have done something similar or can see some problems.

Comment: why not doing DFS right away without preparing those histories? that would save a lot of time if DFS reaches the LCA quickly, and it's not going to take more than O(n) anyway. history method takes O(n) for scanning all nodes + additional space for keeping those histories + designing an algorithm for finding LCA by history

Comment: Our initial version did: start from the 2 given nodes, walk backward, check each node (or 2 nodes if it is a merge point) if it is a CA, stop when 1st found. This doesn't guarantee that the found CA is one of the LCA's and it's checking a limited past of each node, but even so, the no of nodes it was checking was unacceptable in our case.